# Reliably reconnect to the server TCPClient C#

Tags: c#, tcpclient, reconnect

I am having trouble reconnecting a TCPClient (actual class name from C#) to its server. Is there a well defined way of doing this? Do I need to manage the tcp connection at the server as well if a client is trying to reconnect on the same port,

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "actual class name from C#"? (The .NET framework type is TcpClient, not TCPClient. If you mean some third-party TCPClient class, you should tell us what it is.)

Comment: Guessing with just the information given, you're probably trying to reuse the same connection to 'reconnect' rather than making a new connection. You can make a new connection to the same server, but you can't reconnect a broken connection itself. Once a connection is broken, it should be discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you should do it the same way that you first connected to it. 
Just don't forget to close the connection before trying to reconnect.

Maybe a little bit more info is needed because maybe your trouble is elsewhere.

Do you call a simple "Receive" command and then close the connection and try to reconnect later.
Or are you trying to "BeginReceived" (Async connection) then you would need to handle the ObjectDisposed Exception when you will disconnect and after that reconnect